# Open Google Sheets using a link to a .xlsx file

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a webpage that has a list with several Excel file links.
Let's say one of the links is: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.xlsx

Is it possible to add a button that opens this file directly on Google Sheets without integrating using a SDK? Do they have an endpoint that receives a url and opens on Google Sheets (similar to what they have for PDFs)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask you about `without integrating using a SDK`? And in your goal, do you want to edit the excel file after the file was opened?

Comment: I meant without asking for the user account permission to change their Google Drive files. No editing, just preview.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your URL can directly show the preview of excel file, you can open it on the dialog opened on Spreadsheet. But if your URL cannot be used for showing as the preview of excel file, the excel file is required to be hosted to Google Drive and OneDrive. About these methods, I think that the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui` is used, because at the dialog, Javascript can be used. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.